# error while using nestedcv.glmnet package: invalid times argument

Tags: r, validation, nested, predict, glmnet

I am using nestcv.glmnet function from nestedcv package to train a model. But I am getting an error.
I have also attache my data:

```
dput(y_train[1:5])
c(`GTEX-14LZ3` = 1.30204166535137, `GTEX-13QJC` = 0.767120841644941,
`GTEX-11DZ1` = 0.281033091212483, `GTEX-14C5O` = -0.589082784743255,
`GTEX-1F7RK` = -0.210001426831818)
> dput(x_train[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dim = c(5L,
5L), dimnames = list(c("GTEX-14LZ3", "GTEX-13QJC", "GTEX-11DZ1",
"GTEX-14C5O", "GTEX-1F7RK"), c("22_45255830_C_T_b38", "22_45255847_C_T_b38",
"22_45256000_C_T_b38", "22_45256064_A_G_b38", "22_45256248_A_G_b38"
)))




 fit2 <- nestcv.glmnet(y_train,x_train, family = "gaussian", alphaSet = 0.5,
n_outer_folds = 5,n_inner_folds=10,filterFUN = wilcoxon_filter)
Error in rep(1, N) : invalid 'times' argument
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue.
Thank you